# How query bit operator in postgresql jsonb column

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-14, postgresql-json

I have a table as follows in PostgreSQL:

```
id | access
--------------------------
1  | [{"id": 1, "user":"user1", "permission": 1}, {"id": 2, "user":"user2", "permission": 3}]
2  | [{"id": 1, "user":"user1", "permission": 3}, {"id": 2, "user":"user2", "permission": 7}]
```

I want to get records with `user: "user1"` and `permission: 2`(in other words `permission & 2 = 2`). The response for the above example is record with id 2. My query for filter user is as follows but I can't handled it for permission:

```
Select * from my_table where jsonb_path_exists("access", '$[*] ? (@.user == "user1")')
```

What do I add to query for filtering permission?

Update: Permissions are in bit codec. some samples are as followes:

- 1 -> `001`
- 2 -> `010`
- 3 -> `011`
- 4 -> `100`
- 5 -> `101`
- 6 -> `110`

Comment: You say `user: "user1"` and `permission: 2` and according to you row with `id`=2 satisfies this. But I don't see any element inside the array where value of `permission` is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no bitwise operators in SQL/JSON Path Language. Use an additional condition with `jsonb_path_query_first()`

```sql
select *
from my_table
where jsonb_path_exists("access", '$[*] ? (@.user == "user1")')
and jsonb_path_query_first("access", '$[*] ? (@.user == "user1").permission')::int & 2 = 2
```

or the function `jsonb_array_elements()` in lateral join

```sql
select t.* 
from my_table t
cross join jsonb_array_elements(access)
where value->>'user' = 'user1'
and (value->>'permission')::int & 2 = 2
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/yzZCBkpE?hide=8)

Comment: Note that the first one doesn't necessarily pick the `permission` from the array element of the one with "user1". You would need to use `jsonb_path_query_first("access", '$[*] ? (@user == "user1").permission')::int & 2 = 2`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - You are definitely right. The query corrected, thanks.